# After enabling two-factor authentication, I no longer have the option to use my iCloud password to log in

Tags: macos, apple-id, password, login

I enabled two-factor authentication (the new one available in iOS 9, OS X 10.11, etc., *not* the old two-step verification) for my Apple ID. After doing so, my MBP prompted me to change my password saying that I couldn't use my iCloud password to log in to it anymore, so I changed it. I expected the same thing to happen on my iMac, but it didn't. iMac is still happily using my iCloud password to log into my local account. Going into Users & Groups & clicking "Change Password" for my account on my iMac, I still get the same old "Use iCloud password..." option, but on my MBP I don't have that option.

Is this expected behavior? Why can I still use my iCloud password on my iMac, but not on my MBP?

Comment: What version OS is your iMac running vs. what OS is your Macbook running?

Comment: Both are running 10.11.4

Comment: Have you tried logging out of iCloud on the iMac and then signing back in? I would assume perhaps a stuck preference file or something similar, since it should not matter the hardware you are running for iCloud passwords on login.

Comment: Ah, I had not logged out / in on my iMac. After doing that, I don't have the option to use my iCloud password there either anymore. It seems strange to me that it wouldn't automacitally enforce that... If you'd like to write that up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: glad to hear it's working now! I'll post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest logging out and then back into iCloud on the affected machine to ensure that it has the most current and up-to-date settings. It is likely that there is just something stuck, considering both systems are running the same OS.