# El Capitan: How do I use my Apple ID password to log in after a temporary password change?

Tags: icloud, macos, apple-id, password

Today, I reset my User password to a temporary password for use in a service appointment. Previously, the account was using my iCloud password to log in, and I thought I could change it back to that after the service.

When the service was completed, I used the Users & Groups preference pane to reset my password again, but the option to use my iCloud password to log in is no longer present.

Based on [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232165/after-enabling-two-factor-authentication-i-no-longer-have-the-option-to-use-my?newreg=399f8e63e26946468466beb970181206), I logged out of iCloud and logged back in from the iCloud preference pane, but the option to use my use my iCloud password is still not presented when I initiate a password reset in the Users & Groups preference pane.

Is there a known solution to this issue? If not what steps might I take to diagnose the problem?

- MacBookPro11,1
- OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)

Comment: Do you have 2FA enabled?

Comment: Go to appleid.apple.com -> Security and you can see if you have it enabled

Comment: @user104317, I can't log in. When I enter my login info and submit, I get a modal window titled "Update Apple ID", prompting me to "Verify Email Address". My email address is entered into a field, and I can click "Cancel" or "Continue". Clicking "Continue" brings me to the same modal window, with the address field highlighted. Clicking "Continue" again brings up an error message saying that my email address is already in use. But I'm not creating a new ID.

Comment: I do not know why that is happening

Comment: See correct answer below from @quanlong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the following command in Terminal, then restart your Mac. The iCloud password will appear again.

```
sudo dscl . append /Users/`users` AuthenticationAuthority ";AppleID;ID@APPLE.COM"
```

And do **NOT** forget to change **ID@APPLE.COM** yo your real Apple ID.

Comment: This works. Thanks @quanlong. Longer blog post for those that are interested http://www.mac.si/posts/icloudpassword.html

Answer (score 1):

With OS X 10.11.4 the option to use iCloud password is no longer available.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: While it's true that it's no longer available by default or "out of the box", the functionality does indeed appear to be present. See the answer for @quanlong above. I've confirmed personally that this does, in fact, appear to work just fine. The original blog post seems to be this http://www.mac.si/posts/icloudpassword.html

Answer (score 1):

I got bit by this too. Changes login from iCloud password to custom and...logging in via iCloud password is indeed no longer available.

So, until this changes, to paraphrase (badly) an old Willie Nelson song, Mama, don't let your children grow-up to change their password preferences from iCloud password.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions.  Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions.  To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - From Review -

Answer (score 0):

There's explicit [help section at official Apple support website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204071).

#### What to do after you change your Apple ID email address or password

After you change your Apple ID email address or password, you might need to update your sign-in information with any Apple services that you're using.

> #### Mac with OS X Mountain Lion or later
>
> Choose `Apple menu` > `System Preferences`, then click `iCloud`.
>
> - If you're signed out, enter your updated Apple ID and password to sign in. The data in iCloud will automatically appear on your device after you sign in.
> - If you're signed in with your previous Apple ID:
>
>   1. Click [`Sign Out`](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14353). Depending on what iCloud options are turned on, you'll be asked if you want to **[make copies](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204055) or delete iCloud data** (Contacts, Calendar, Reminders, Bookmarks, Photo Stream) from your Mac. Your data will remain in iCloud and will be updated on your device when you sign in to iCloud again.
>   2. Enter your updated Apple ID and password to sign in.

If you experience problems with iOS as well, then execute instructions from this page: [If iCloud asks you for the password to your previous Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203828)

Comment: I tried signing out of icloud it did not help and we changed our computer passwords not our icloud passwords

Comment: The OP said he tried signing in and out of icloud too

Comment: @user104317, who we? :) was you doing this together with OP, or what? The **subject** and description is about *How do I use my **Apple ID password to log in** after a temporary password change?*. It's about AppleID, but not about computer password. Or that is the confusion and the question has to be clarified.

Comment: The computer password was changed both I and the OP did not change the icloud password. The OP and I want to login to our computers with our Apple ID however the OP and I are not presented with the dialogue asking if you want to use your Apple ID to login.

Comment: "**_Users & Groups preference pane_**" I'm pretty sure the OP is trying to change the computer password.

Comment: hm, it seems you might be right, @user104317. I will take a look tomorrow, how I can help. I checked - I have this button available in OSX, no problems occur in my OS X v.10.11.3 (15D21), so can't reproduce right now. I bet the thing is connected with some password hash being saved, and which was not renewed after the password change (for example, without internet connection).

Comment: I believe this might be related to having 2FA enabled. I have 2FA enabled and OP linked to a [thread](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232165/after-enabling-two-factor-authentication-i-no-longer-have-the-option-to-use-my?newreg=399f8e63e26946468466beb970181206) metioning 2FA.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have two-factor authentication enabled. How can I tell?

Comment: The question field wasn't long enough to include all the details, and my hope was to clarify in the body of the post. @user104317 picked up on my intended meaning: I didn't change my Apple ID or Apple ID password, just my User password on a MacBook Pro. Now I want to change it back to logging in with my Apple ID, like I did before the temporary password change.